# Netbeans building GUI; how do I disable Netbeans from disallowing me to edit text?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I find it annoying that Netbeans tries to disable editing the source code whenever I use the GUI builder utility.  I have searched in Google but could not find an answer:

How do I disable Netbeans from disallowing me to edit my source code? Is this a bug because whenever I right click the .java file, I am able to edit again.

Comment: netbeans doesn't allow you to edit the code directly because conflicts may occur when you change stuff in the designer (i.e netbeans adding its own code). This is why the code tab in the properties windows is used so you can write code specifying where it should lie (after creation of your Label2 for example, then write that in Post_Creation Code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a bug. In fact netbeans doesn't allow you to edit the source code in the `initcomponents()` method. In the properties window (Ctrl+ Shift+ 7) where you see the main tabs (properties, binding, events and code), after choosing a component and viewing its properties window, if you choose code you can add whatever code you want as in Custom-Creation code, Pre-Creation code, Post-Creation code, pre-Init code, Post-Init Code.....

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the Netbeans generated code is not a good idea - Netbeans will revert your changes again.